# Where can I find Spring 4 OSGi bundles

Tags: spring, osgi

Where can I find OSGi bundles for Spring 4? I checked http://ebr.springsource.com/ but can only find Spring 3.2.x and the artifacts in Maven Central are not bundles.

**Clarification**

I'm not looking for Spring DM or similar. I'm looking for the "Spring Framework" JARs (spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, …) as OSGi bundles. I'm not trying to create an application context in an OSGi environment. I just need the (exception) classes in an OSGi environment.

Comment: This thread http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=71606 suggests it all moved to http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/ a while ago.

Comment: The way I read it that was Spring DM. That's not what I'm looking for. I'm just looking for spring-core, spring-context, spring-beans, … OSGi bundles.

Comment: Good question. I found a list of repos here https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework:spring-core/4.0.0.RELEASE. Seems after 3.2.5 the bundles are not there.

Comment: That spring ebr repo is going away (look at the FAQs). I guess you can "osgify" your own bundles :) Just create a POM with say spring-core dependency then using the bnd plugin private-package everything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring will **NOT** support any further releases as OSGi bundles. The official support has been stopped with spring 3.2.4 (although you could find 3.2.5 artifacts [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/search?query=spring&includeLibraries=true&_includeLibraries=on&includeBundles=true&_includeBundles=on&version=), contradicting the statement made in the [Eclipse Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/513222/))

Glyn Normington from Spring source acknowledged that in several places, see here:

- [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/glynnormington/status/425280920888016896)
- [Eclipse Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/513222/)

However, there is hope. On the Karaf - dev list, one can read that they intend to support spring libraries in the ServiceMix project. Details in the entire thread see [here](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Spring-OSGi-bundles-no-longer-being-released-td4031212.html).

Answer (score 15):

I found ServiceMix had provided OSGi-fy Spring bundles up to ver. 4.1.4, 
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop/

I tried it in my osgi Bundle project, to set dependeny like that :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE_3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Run in Felix a found sprint bundles are activated :

```
START LEVEL 1
 ID|State      |Level|Name
...
5|Resolved   |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-expression (4.1.1.RELEASE_3)
6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
7|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.12.1)
8|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
...
10|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-context (4.1.1.RELEASE_3)
11|Active     |    1|Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: spring-core (4.1.1.RELEASE_3)
....
```

But in it's latest release 5.4.0, ServiceMix only include spring 3.2.11.

Is there any risk when use spring 4.1.1 in my OSGi environment?

Comment: I have found a problem about use Spring in OSGi environment.Spring Couldn't load schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd' resource embedded in spring bundle.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException will occur when create ClassPathXmlApplicationContext without internet connection.Are there any way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 13):

Spring source stopped creating jars with OSGI heaaders last year:
http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/10/spring-osgi-gradle/

I do not think you will get an official maven repo containing OSGI bundles for spring. We use http://ebr.springsource.com/ frequently for OSGI bundles, but even that does not contain any version after 3.2

Could not add as comment due to low repo, hence adding as answer.

Comment: Something official would be nice whether the bundles will eventually show up in EBR or not.

Answer (score 6):

I must say that migrating Spring to OSGi is still live in Apache ServiceMix.
Get the latest(4.0.2.RELEASE) Spring artifacts with OSGi-enabled manifest from [maven repo](http://maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop/4.0.2.RELEASE_1/)

Comment: This is no longer true. With the release of Apache Servicemix 5.1.1, Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE osgi bundles are no longer available.

Comment: Update: The Spring 4.0.5 release is once again back in Servicemix 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

its a little bit tricky to find, here is the link for the OSGi bundle

http://docs.spring.io/downloads/nightly/release-download.php?project=OSGI

and for all spring projects

http://docs.spring.io/downloads/nightly/release-download.php

Comment: None of these are the libraries I'm looking for. I'm not looking for Spring-OSGi and the newest version it contains seem to be 3.1.4.