# Spring Dynamic Modules - is it alive project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, osgi

Spring Dynamic Modules - is it alive project?

For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181154/where-can-i-find-spring-4-osgi-bundles) has info what "Spring will NOT support any further releases as OSGi bundles. ". But [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-osgi/docs/current/reference/html/) has Spring Dynamic Modules Reference Guide, where no info about discontinuing of the project.

Comment: This sort of question should probably go elsewhere, for example to http://www.programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the project is moved to Eclipse, it is more dead than alive. Pivotal has abandoned the project, which makes the Eclipse move more a code dump than a serious attempt to create an open source project. I would not advise building on top of it.

Comment: As of 2018-MAY-14, the Eclipse Gemini Blueprint (the successor of DM) seems to be working on a new release (3.0.0) which integrates Spring 5. So, maybe not completely dead. Spring DM is used in Atlassian JIRA and in JBoss Fuse so hopefully they invest some effort to bring this on.

Comment: The project never progressed beyond the first milestone for version 3.0 and seems quite dead: https://git.eclipse.org/c/gemini.blueprint/org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.git

Answer (score 6):

Its now Eclipse Gemini Blueprint, the change is described in brief here

http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/eclipse-migration.html

The fact that is never mentioned in the reference guide is strange for me also. Especially considering *"While the project name has changed (to Eclipse Gemini Blueprint) and significant efforts have been made to reflect this in the project documentation and resources, there might be places that we have missed; if you find any, please report them to us."*

Comment: 404 for your migration guide link, but gemini plueprint page is ok http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/

Answer (score 0):

Working migration guide link: http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/migration/