# Unable to install Spring-DM (OSGI) 1.2.1 bundles in apache karaf 4.2.1?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi, spring-dm

I am trying to deploy my existing project which has built-in Spring-DM (OSGI) 1.2.1 in apache karaf 4.2.1 (Runtime) but bundle not getting installed properly.
**Does apache karaf 4.2.1 support Spring-DM (OSGI) 1.2.1?**
I know spring-dm (OSGI) 1.2.1 has no longer support from spring officially and it's moved to eclipse as an eclipse-Gemini project name. I have gone through some link mentioned below:
[Spring Dynamic Modules - is it alive project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958343/spring-dynamic-modules-is-it-alive-project)

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, gotta switch to blueprint.xml

Answer (score 1):

Spring DM morphed into Blueprint some time ago. You should be using that instead of Spring-DM.

Alternatively you can use the annotations in DS instead or PAX CDI.

Comment: I should have added a follow up question, is there a reason you can't move to Blueprint? Spring-DM was contributed as part of Blueprint so the move shouldn't be terribly painful.